# Do a Postback with Angular and a Single Page Application

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, angular2-forms, mercadopago

I'm integrating an Angular application with an external js that injects some code for payment processing and needs to have a form that allows postback (method="post"). I was able to use the tag ngNoForm but as this is a Single Page Application,  it doesn't allow me to do a postback. Is there any solution or workaround for this that anyone could recommend me?

Thank you
Ariel

Comment: The error I'm getting when I'm trying to do a action="/process-payment" method="post" is The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.

Of course, the /index.html does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do a HTTP POST with the data collected by your form.

```
var body = "account=" + model.account + "&amount=" + model.amount+ "&pin=" + model.pin;
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/process-payment", body).subscribe((data) => {});
```